# How to use .startsWith with SASS

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I have a SASS condition like this it works as I expected but as you can see It is too long and I want to refactor it. How can I use something like JavaScript's startsWith() or includes() prototype?

```
@if $styleName == margin or $styleName == margin-top or $styleName == margin-right or $styleName == margin-bottom or $styleName == margin-left {
//..something happens there
}
```

I'm looking for a solution like:

```
@if $styleName.startsWith('margin'){
//..something happens there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if str-index($styleName, "margin") {}
```